# Prove that $\vec{Q}-\vec{X}(t_o)$ is perpendicular to the curve at the point $\vec{X}(t_o)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This problem is from *Calculus of Several variables by Serge Lang*. It says

Let $\vec{X}(t)$ be a differentiable curve (by curve he probably means a vector valued function) defined on an open interval, Let $Q$ be a point that is not on the curve.

The first question says to find the formula for the distance between $Q$ And a point on the curve.

this one is pretty straightforward, the formula is $$D(Q,X(t))=\sqrt{(\vec{Q}-\vec{X}(t))\cdot (\vec{Q}-\vec{X}(t))}$$
The second question:
If $X(t_o)$ is a point on the curve such that the distance formula tends to its minimum,Prove that $\vec{Q}-\vec{X}(t_o)$ is perpendicular to the curve at the point $\vec{X}(t_o)$

So this one i don’t have any clue to attack it, i just know that proving the statement in the second question is equivalent to proving that $$(\vec{Q}-\vec{X}(t_o)) \cdot\vec{X’}(t_o)=0 $$

Comment: What means your square root of vectors ?  Secondly, hint, what is the coefficient of the tangent to the curve drawn by $X(t)$ at the point $X(t_0)$ ? What is a normal director to that tangent ?

Comment: See the edit @EDX

Comment: What do you mean by the coefficient of the tangent to the curve? @EDX

Comment: So if you prefer what is a director vector of your tangent ?

Comment: @EDX well basically it is $X’(t_o)$

Comment: So you've proven your assertion

Comment: Sorry i forgot something about the question, see the edit

Comment: Hint: Differentiate your distance

Comment: I didn’t get anything from that @EDX